# Determine network mask for CIDR prefix

Tags: bash

I fixed my problem, thanks to all that tried to help me.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter you ip"
read ip
case $ip in
```

Change CIDR address to quad-style

```
*.*.*.*/*)
b=`echo $ip | cut -d/ -f1`
a=`echo $ip | cut -d/ -f2`

if [ $a -eq 24 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.0"
elif [ $a -eq 25 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.128"
elif [ $a -eq 26 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.192"
elif [ $a -eq 27 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.224"
elif [ $a -eq 28 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.240"
elif [ $a -eq 29 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.248"
elif [ $a -eq 30 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.252"
elif [ $a -eq 31 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.254"
elif [ $a -eq 32 ];then
   echo "$b 255.255.255.255"
fi
;;
```

Opposite

```
 *.*.*.*\ *.*.*.*)
c=`echo $ip | awk '{print $1}'`
d=`echo $ip | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ $d == 255.255.255.0 ];then
echo "$c/24"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.128 ];then
echo "$c/25"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.192 ];then
echo "$c/26"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.224 ];then
echo "$c/27"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.240 ];then
echo "$c/28"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.248 ];then
echo "$c/29"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.252 ];then
echo "$c/30"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.254 ];then
echo "$c/31"
elif [ $d == 255.255.255.255 ];then
echo "$c/32"
fi

;;
```

If u write fel format of ip address

```
*)
echo "please enter a valid ip address"

esac
```

> in this script u can convert ip address from CIDR address to quad-style and opposite

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Im new beginner in linux, so i just need a hint how can i start

Comment: http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Comment: i studied the basic script in bash, but i dont know how to start with this issue

Comment: The "192.168.1.0" part has nothing to do with "/24" == "255.255.255.0".

Comment: ok, but what will happen if the ip changed or /24 become /23?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will be in much better position if you use Python for this.
The netaddr module can help you perform those calculations very easily.

Netaddr = http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html

If you're on a linux system, you can use the ipcalc program to do those calculations also.

Comment: i get task to do it by script with linux "bash"